# Storing a SARIMAX model for export?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, time-series, statsmodels, modeling

I ran a lengthy (for my machine) test of all possible combinations of the parameters for a time series analysis.  Can I somehow save the object for later use on my machine or export for use by a colleague?

I have a screenshot of the best model's results, which I can always reenter later, but I want to try and save the actual `best_model` object.

I am using Jupyter Notebooks and Python.

```
print(type(best_model))
print(best_model)

<class 'statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAXResultsWrapper'>
<statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAXResultsWrapper object at 0x7fc9888e6b00>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pickle models and results in statmodels. These can be reloaded later on the same version of statsmodels.